# Mutual SSL handshake failing after Client CertificateVerify step

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

While calling an external Api secured using Mutual SSL, getting the  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Went through the ssl debug logs and seems like client and server are able to exchange and validate the certificate and communication is failing after that step.

Putting relevant SSL debug logs :
^^^ClientHello, TLSv1.2
^^^List of CipherSuites
^^^ServerHello, TLSv1.2
^^^Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
** Certificate chain
..............................
................................
^^^CertificateRequest
............
^^^ServerHelloDone
^^^Certificate chain
..................
....................
**no IV derived for this protocol**
**CertificateVerify**
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 46, 243, 175, 158, 127, 112, 161, 153, 5, 195, 3, 35 }

---

main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

**Communication is failing after certificateverify step, not sure if it is due to "no IV derived for this protocol".** Can someone throw some light on this, what could be possible reason for failure after client certificateverify step. Also for the client I am using Java 8 with Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength